# Problema sobre arreglos en sql server

Tags: base-de-datos

Mi problema es asi.

Tengo una Base de Datos Sql Server

En mi Base de datos tengo un tabla con un campo varbinary, alli dentro se encuentra un contenido en forma de arreglos de binarios y necesito volverlo un archivo fisico

He buscado mucho, y nadie me ha podido decir como hacer un SELECT que me ayude a ver que hay dentro, o como convertirlo o algo.

Saludos, y gracias